# iOS in-app payments without AppStore

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, payment

I am writing iOS client-server game.

Client side: 
- server comunication, 
- game user interface etc.

Server side: 
- logic for game 
- responsible for delivering some data and logic for iOS client 
- manage payments 
- manage user privilages

In my system I have my own virtual currency. User can buy virtual money via payment system.
User can spent virtual money in game. For spending money he builds his own reputation in my own loyalty program. For some level of loyalty he will have some privilages, for example access for other functionality of app.

As I mentioned, server will responsible for payments, using variety of payments system (paypal, sms, etc.) 
And now... 
I have a question: Can I use in this case any other payment systems without Apple's IAP? 
I don't want to use it, because my server manages payments for all platforms. 
I would like to make payments in iOS app using WebViews. Is it possible?

Thanks for replies :)

Answer (score 3):

You must use IAP, since you payments are providing functionalities to your game.

From [apple review guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#in-app-purchase):

> If you want to **unlock features or functionality within your app**, (by
>   way of example: subscriptions, **in-game currencies**, game levels, access
>   to premium content, or unlocking a full version), you **must use in-app
>   purchase**. **Apps may not include buttons, external links, or other calls
>   to action that direct customers to purchasing mechanisms other than
>   IAP**. 
> Any credits or in-game currencies purchased via IAP must be
>   consumed within the app and may not expire, and you should make sure
>   you have a restore mechanism for any restorable in-app purchases.
>   Remember to assign the correct purchasability type or your app will be
>   rejected. 
> Apps should not directly or indirectly enable gifting of IAP
>   content, features, or consumable items to others. 
> Apps distributed via
>   the Mac App Store may host plug-ins or extensions that are enabled
>   with mechanisms other than the App Store.